# Why does the simplest neural network work worse than logistic regression

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm new to neural networks, and I'm trying to write my first network.
Here's the data I'm trying to train her on.

```
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1024,n_features=2, n_informative=2, n_redundant=0, n_classes=2, random_state=2)
```

[Generated data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0STa.png)

Here is my network:

```
def f(x):
  return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def df(x):
  return f(x)*(1-f(x))

def init():
  np.random.seed(42)
  W1 = np.random.rand(2,2)
  W2 = np.random.rand(1,2)
  return W1,W2

def go_forward(inp,W1,W2):
  sum = np.dot(W1,inp)
  out = np.array([f(x) for x in sum])

  sum_1 = np.dot(W2,out)
  out_1 = f(sum_1)
  y  = 1 if out_1>0.5 else 0 
  return (y,out)

def train_one_epoch(X_train,y_train,W2,W1,lr):
  err = []
  for k in range(len(X_train)):
    ind = np.random.randint(0,len(X_train))
    x,y = X_train[ind],y_train[ind]
    pred, out = go_forward(x,W1,W2)
    e = pred - y
    delta = e*df(pred)
    W2 = W2 - lr*delta*out

    delta2  = W2*delta*df(out)
    W1 = W1 - np.array(x)*delta2*lr
    err.append(e)
  return W1,W2,np.mean(np.array(err))


epoch = 100
lr = 0.01
err = []
W1,W2 = init()
for e in range(epoch):
  W1,W2,e = train_one_epoch(X_train,y_train,W2,W1,lr)
  err.append(e)
```

The error graph is bothering me
[error graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbXvi.png)

here is an accuracy comparison

My Network  - 0.751953125

sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression - 0.974609375

[Test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBIqD.png)
[My Network Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QISql.png)
[Results sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgyDS.png)

I'm at a loss why the network can't solve such a simple problem

I have tried changing the number of epochs, but it does not lead to anything.

Comment: (1) in `go_forward` you return `out`, I think you meant to return `out_1`. (2) make a larger neural network (higher size of `W1` / `W2`

Comment: @alexey-larionov, thanks for your comment, I need to `out` to calculate the weight change of the first layer of neurons

Comment: increasing the number of neurons in the first layer to 12 really solved the problem, however, I don't quite understand how the number of neurons affects the network? If one layer is a conditional linear regression, then what is one neuron?

Comment: I think it's because your weight changes are too chaotic, because they're computed from 1 datapoint, and then immediately update the weights, while LogisticRegression analyses all the dataset before each step. Also the "solver" argument of the LogisticRegression might do complicated optimization way better than plain "gradient descent" of your network. Maybe you can get better results with your neural network. Try 2 neurons and much lower learning rate. Maybe your current learning rate was very high and caused long "jumps" in terms of weight updates, disturbing the convergence